# Chroot SSH - Command not found

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, chroot

I have a bin directory in my chroot directory that contains commands like bash date ls...etc

If i simply chroot to my chroot directory. i am still able to invoke commands listed in the /bin.

However when i access through ssh (I ssh into another user that is attached to the chroot directory), i am unable to execute any commands from the /bin. It prompted "command not found".

on the other hand, if I cd into the bin directory - cd bin... I can invoked the ls command - ./ls (this is just to prove that I am in the correct chroot directory after I ssh in.)

I am following this link to set up chroot for my ssh access. https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/

Any solution to this?

Comment: It sounds like your `PATH` is not set to include `/bin`. You can check with `echo $PATH`.

Comment: yes it seems that the path is not correct, how I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `/bin` is not in the user's `$PATH` environment variable; a variable which tells the shell where to look for executables.

Since you're using BASH you can simply edit `/etc/profile` in the chroot to add the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin
```